# dropdown codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I am new in codeIgniter and I having a bit of trouble with my database and dropdown menu.

my model

```
function list_kategori(){
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table1);
    $option = array();
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $options[$row['id_cat']] =$row['categori'];
    }
    return $options;

}
```

my Controller

```
public function listkategori(){
    $data['kategori']=$this->Mtugasuas->list_kategori();
    $data ['test'] = form_dropdown('kategori', $data);

}
```

my View

```
<?php
echo form_open('tugasuas/listkategori');
echo $test;
echo form_close();
?>
```

Error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: test

Filename: blackcoffe/add.php

Line Number: 12
```

What Am I doing wrong?
thx for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the variable to view file from controller using this ...

```
 $this->load->view('view_file_name',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't going to work at all, there is at least one mistake beyond what Venkat mentions, the fact that you're trying to populate the dropdown with $data when the actual data is in $data['kategori'], it's also not great practice and will lead to hugely messy controllers to try building your form elements in the controller (to be honest I'm not even positive that will work, in theory it should but...

Your Controller

```
public function listkategori(){
    $data['kategori']=$this->Mtugasuas->list_kategori();
    $this->load->view('viewName',$data);
    //load the view with $data this way you can pass multiple variables to the same view.

}
```

Your View

```
<?php
    echo form_open('tugasuas/listkategori');
    echo form_dropdown('kategori', $kategori);
    echo form_close();
?>
```